# Is there a way to make this code shorter

Tags: javascript, slider

First one is this

```
  function show1(){
    document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-4").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-5").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
```

I have like 50 of those...

Is there a way to group a bunch of them in an array or something? And just to let you know i'm quite the newbie in all of this, so when you see this as a catastrophe

```
  /* Slide 1 */
  function show1(){
    document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-4").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-5").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show2(){
    document.getElementById("pic-2").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-4").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-5").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show3(){
    document.getElementById("pic-3").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-4").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-5").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show4(){
    document.getElementById("pic-4").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-5").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show5(){
    document.getElementById("pic-5").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-3").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-4").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 2 */
  function show21(){
    document.getElementById("pic-21").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-22").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-23").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-24").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-25").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show22(){
    document.getElementById("pic-22").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-21").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-23").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-24").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-25").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show23(){
    document.getElementById("pic-23").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-22").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-21").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-24").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-25").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show24(){
    document.getElementById("pic-24").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-22").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-23").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-21").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-25").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show25(){
    document.getElementById("pic-25").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-22").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-23").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-24").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-21").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 3 */
  function show31(){
    document.getElementById("pic-31").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-32").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-33").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-34").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-35").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show32(){
    document.getElementById("pic-32").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-31").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-33").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-34").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-35").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show33(){
    document.getElementById("pic-33").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-32").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-31").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-34").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-35").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show34(){
    document.getElementById("pic-34").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-32").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-33").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-31").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-35").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show35(){
    document.getElementById("pic-35").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-32").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-33").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-34").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-31").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 4 */
  function show41(){
    document.getElementById("pic-41").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-42").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-43").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-44").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-45").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show42(){
    document.getElementById("pic-42").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-41").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-43").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-44").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-45").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show43(){
    document.getElementById("pic-43").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-42").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-41").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-44").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-45").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show44(){
    document.getElementById("pic-44").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-42").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-43").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-41").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-45").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show45(){
    document.getElementById("pic-45").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-42").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-43").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-44").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-41").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 5 */
  function show51(){
    document.getElementById("pic-51").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-52").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-53").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-54").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-55").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show52(){
    document.getElementById("pic-52").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-51").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-53").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-54").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-55").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show53(){
    document.getElementById("pic-53").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-52").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-51").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-54").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-55").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show54(){
    document.getElementById("pic-54").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-52").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-53").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-51").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-55").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show55(){
    document.getElementById("pic-55").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-52").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-53").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-54").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-51").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 6 */
  function show1(){
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show62(){
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show63(){
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show64(){
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show65(){
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 6 */
  function show61(){
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show62(){
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show63(){
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show64(){
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show65(){
    document.getElementById("pic-65").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-62").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-63").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-64").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-61").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 7 */
  function show71(){
    document.getElementById("pic-71").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-72").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-73").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-74").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-75").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show72(){
    document.getElementById("pic-72").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-71").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-73").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-74").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-75").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show73(){
    document.getElementById("pic-73").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-72").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-71").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-74").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-75").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show74(){
    document.getElementById("pic-74").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-72").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-73").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-71").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-75").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show75(){
    document.getElementById("pic-75").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-72").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-73").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-74").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-71").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 8 */
  function show81(){
    document.getElementById("pic-81").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-82").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-83").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-84").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-85").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show82(){
    document.getElementById("pic-82").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-81").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-83").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-84").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-85").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show83(){
    document.getElementById("pic-83").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-82").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-81").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-84").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-85").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show84(){
    document.getElementById("pic-84").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-82").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-83").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-81").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-85").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show85(){
    document.getElementById("pic-85").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-82").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-83").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-84").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-81").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 9 */
  function show91(){
    document.getElementById("pic-91").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-92").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-93").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-94").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-95").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show92(){
    document.getElementById("pic-92").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-91").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-93").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-94").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-95").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show93(){
    document.getElementById("pic-93").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-92").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-91").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-94").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-95").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show94(){
    document.getElementById("pic-94").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-92").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-93").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-91").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-95").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show95(){
    document.getElementById("pic-95").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-92").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-93").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-94").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-91").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  /* Slide 10 */
  function show101(){
    document.getElementById("pic-101").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-102").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-103").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-104").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-105").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show102(){
    document.getElementById("pic-102").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-101").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-103").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-104").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-105").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show103(){
    document.getElementById("pic-103").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-102").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-101").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-104").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-105").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show104(){
    document.getElementById("pic-104").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-102").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-103").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-101").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-105").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  function show105(){
    document.getElementById("pic-105").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pic-102").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-103").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-104").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-101").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
```

I see it as a victory -lol. But seriously, i'm not that bright but even i think that there is a mach much easier way than this.

And just to give you an overview of what is this script a part of:

Simple slider with 10 slides 
Each slide has 5 buttons
When one of those buttons is hovered a div hat contains a certain picture appears while the others become hidden.

So i do believe that i need that big number of functions, but i think that there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```
        function show(show, pictures) {
  for (i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) { 
        document.getElementById(pictures[i]).style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
   document.getElementById(show).style.visibility = "visible";
}

show('pic-1', ["pic-1","pic-2", "pic-3"]);
```

Comment: Problem with that solution is that everytime he adds a new element, he must add to the array. And as the OP said, he has like 50 of that. Not the best solution imo.

Comment: @Isuckatprogramming "Even the death is not for less, then he costs the life.". The OP can declare different array's and give a dedicated array to the function.

Comment: @reporter As a non-native english speaker I didn't quite get the reference.

Comment: @Isuckatprogramming I am also a non-native english speaker :-). I think this way is not really bad. The author just didn't realise the system behind the id's from all elements.

Comment: @reporter True, but if the OP added the same class to every image then it would a lot easier to obtain all of them by using `document.getElementsByClassName()` then to write all of them by hand as suggested above. But that's just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide / make visible some of the elements in your code simultaneously, you can always add to them matching classes and unit all your actions to one or two pieces of code.

for example:

```
  function show1(){
    $('.Class_for_all_elements_you_want_to_hide').css('display', 'none');
  }
```

the same should be done for the once's you need to display, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's depends upon your usage..
**if you want to hide all images then with single line of code you can do that**
like

```
$('img').hide();
```

of else if you know what all images are hide in a corresponding event then you can **set all these images under a certain class**  and hide that class

```
 $('.classname').css('display', 'none');
```

or else you can **set imageids as array** and with the help of a loop you can do that

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(pic, slide) {

document.querySelectorAll("[id^=pic-"+slide+"]").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pic-"+slide+number).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

this code hide all the pictures of the slide and after this shows just the picture you gave by parameter

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9d57a69f/

**Pure Javascript**

```
 showElement('elementIdToShow'); 
 showElement('pic1'); // Call this way to show pic1

    function showElement(id) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pic"); //This might fail in old browser versions. If you want to support those pick up all elements in another way, the logic can continue the same.
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.visibility = "hidden";


        }
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

**If you can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)**

```
showElement('pic1');
function showElement(id) {
    $('.pic').hide(); //Get all elements that contains class called pic and hide it
    $("#"+id).show(); //Get element by a specific ID and show it
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="pic1" class="pic">1</div>
<div id="pic2" class="pic">2</div>
<div id="pic3" class="pic">3</div>
<div id="pic4" class="pic">4</div>
<div id="pic5" class="pic">5</div>
```

Comment: Be careful with the use of 'getElementsByClassName()'. There still existing a lot of browsers, these supports only older versions of Javascript. And there does this method not exists.

Comment: Yep, it depends if he wants support for old versions. In case he wants something really cross-browser, then it's better to use JQuery which handles it well. Or just pick up all the elements in another way. The logic of hide/show can continue the same.

Comment: I'm interested in the jQuery method, could you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: Click on the JQuery that I've added to the answer and take a look at it. In this case, I'm selecting the elements by using a selector, then I fire a function for these elements. The selector '.className' selects all the elements which contains the class name and the selector '#elementId' selects the element with a specific ID. To use it, you have to add the JQuery js. The following link can help you to get started: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try not to re-create the wheel, some awesome library already exists  (you can use your images)

See: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js